# Why did Joe Burrow not have a nameplate?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

[image: Why does NFL player not have a nameplate?]

The photo shows #9 for the Cincinnati Bengals ([Joe Burrow](https://www.espn.com/nfl/player/_/id/3915511/joe-burrow)) playing without a nameplate on his jersey during the Bengals game against the Chiefs on 2nd January 2022. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

Per [Uni-watch](https://uni-watch.com/2022/01/03/monday-morning-uni-watch-267/) and a [Twitter video](https://twitter.com/josephperson/status/1477739261814267906), the nameplate (which was probably not sewn on) was coming loose during the game.  During a play, a Kansas City player (Chris Jones) grabbed it during an attempted tackle and it was removed from the jersey.